# How to retrieve the rootPath (or any other client side info) from language server side?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I am working on a language extention, based on the sample "language server" (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server).

On the server side, I need to know the current folder used by vscode, which, on the client side, would be retrieved by :

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
[...]
let curFolder : string =  vscode.workspace.rootPath;
[...]
```

But if I try to use this on server side,

1. I get a TS compiler error : *error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vscode'*
2. Once client is started (using F5 in client), I'm unable to attach to the server (using F5 in server).

Both my server and client package.json specify :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "vscode": "^0.11.12"
  }
```

My understanding is that the server only communicates with the client via the IConnection object, and thus does not have access to vscode.* data that are maintained on the client side.

My current work around it to use this on server side:

```
connection.sendRequest({ method: "getRootPath" })
.then( (rootPath : string) => {
    [...]
```

and this code on client side:

```
languageClient.onRequest({method: "getRootPath"}, (params : any) : string => {
        return vscode.workspace.rootPath;
} );
```

Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple. The rootPath is provided to the language server at initialization, in the parameters of "connection.onInitialize".

```
connection.onInitialize(
(params) : InitializeResult => {
    connection.console.log("Initialization : " + params.rootPath);
});
```